# Getting Cell Count after network operation

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am trying to get the collectionViewCell count from the network request but the value turns out to be always 0 (to which I initialised the count variable) I want the view to load the cells after I get it's count from the get request.What is it I'm doing wrong I have written this code after `super.viewDidLoad()`.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
    let token = "---------------------------"
    let url = URL(string: "https:----------home.json?token="+token)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        // print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        let jsonWithObjectRoot = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        //  print(json!)
        if let dictionary = jsonWithObjectRoot as? [String: Any] {
            if let data = dictionary["data"] as? [String:Any]{
                if let posts =  data["posts"] as? [Any]{
                    count = posts.count
                    //print(count) //the value here is 2 
                    for object in posts{

                        if let contentString = object as? [String: Any] {
                            print(contentString["title"] as! String)
                            //   print(contentString["entered"]as! String)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
    /* end Request */
    DispatchQueue.main.async{

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: `task.resume()` runs asynchronously hence `reloadData` is triggered before your data has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic **async** case. You network calls are async, so your reload should happen inside the completion of the network call.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
    let token = "---------------------------"
    let url = URL(string: "https:----------home.json?token="+token)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        // print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        let jsonWithObjectRoot = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        //  print(json!)
        if let dictionary = jsonWithObjectRoot as? [String: Any] {
            if let data = dictionary["data"] as? [String:Any]{
                if let posts =  data["posts"] as? [Any]{
                    count = posts.count
                    //print(count) //the value here is 2 
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                    }
                    for object in posts {
                        if let contentString = object as? [String: Any] {
                            print(contentString["title"] as! String)
                            //   print(contentString["entered"]as! String)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    /* end Request */

}
```

Comment: I'm quite new to gcd Thanks for the help that worked perfectly for me

Comment: I'm having the same trouble again but the thing is this time I don't have any collection view , I have a scroll view for which I am getting images from the network. What methods can we use for that i.e  to get correct count in viewdidload

Comment: @ssDON_JOE this seems like a new question. Post this as another question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **reload** after getting `data` from the network

```
count = posts.count
//print(count) //the value here is 2 
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```