# My object array is nil while my data are correct

Tags: json, swift

I try to display my data in a tableView using no framework to parse my data, but when I add my data to my table and debug it, it is nil at the output while my data I retrieve are well parses, have I forgotten something to do?

I use a structure for my parameters as this :

```
    enum Types {
     case School
     case Hospital
     case Station_Essence
     case Restaurant
}

struct Adresse {
    public var title: String
    public var details: String?
    public var type: Types
    public var coordinate: [String: Any]
}
```

and in my ViewController, i proced as this :

```
    class ListMapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TitleTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var MapView: MKMapView!

    var adresse: [Adresse]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TitleTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ListMapTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Adresse")
        self.TitleTableView.delegate = self
        self.TitleTableView.dataSource = self
        guard let POI = URL(string: "https://moc4a-poi.herokuapp.com/") else {
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: POI) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data else { return }
            if let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options:[]) as? [[String: Any]] {
                for data in json {
                    let title = data["title"] as! String
                    let details = data["details"] as? String
                    guard let type = data["type"] as? Int else { return }
                    let valueType = self.valueType(dataType: type)
                    guard let coordinates = data["coordinates"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    self.adresse?.append(Adresse(title: title, details: details, type: valueType, coordinate: coordinates))
                }
            }
            print(self.adresse)
        }
        self.TitleTableView.reloadData()
        task.resume()

    }

    private func valueType(dataType: Int) -> Types {
        if(dataType == 1) {
            return Types.School
        } else if (dataType == 2) {
            return Types.Hospital
        } else if (dataType == 3) {
            return Types.Station_Essence
        } else {
            return Types.Restaurant
        }
    }

}

extension ListMapViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.adresse?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Adresse", for: indexPath) as! ListMapTableViewCell
        if let adresse = self.adresse?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.draw(adresse: adresse)
        }
        return cell
    }


}

extension ListMapViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

Comment: The reload should be done inside the completion of the network on the main thread. This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392288/getting-cell-count-after-network-operation/52392356#52392356

Comment: Ok i added   DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.TitleTableView.reloadData()
        } but the object array of adresse is always nil

Comment: Read the solution in the link carefully and patiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big problems.

1. `self.adresse` is `nil`. You never assign it a value. So all of the `self.adresse?...` do nothing.
2. You call `reloadData` too soon. It needs to be done inside the completion block, after you update the data. And it needs to be on the main queue.

To fix #1, change `var adresse: [Adresse]?` to `var adresse = [Adresse]()`. Then you can get rid of all the `?` after uses of `adresse`.

To fix #2, add:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.TitleTableView.reloadData()
}
```

just after the `print` at the end of the completion block. Don't forget to remove the current call to `reloadData`.